# How to I redefine a dimension?

Tags: webi

I think my problem [SAP WEBI - MultiValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679943/sap-webi-multivalue) may be based on the dimension/detail structure I have to work with. Is there a way that this can be "re-engineered" in the SAP WEBI environment, using variables?

There are only 4 elements that I'm manipulating. I've tried defining all of them as DIMENSION variables. I've tried various combinations of DETAILS of DIMENSIONS. But nothing seems to change.... problem is that I don't even know if what I'm doing is conceptually correct.

Comment: Please, [do not include tags in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/281907), this was discussed multiple times and decision as done to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

To force WEBI to show a value instead of a multivalue as you said, you need to use MAX, MIN or SUM but also you need to specify in what dimension WEBI need to do this.

Try to this and hope it helps.

```
=MAX([Dimension]) In([Column1];[Column2];[Column3];[Column4])
```